# Booking transit hotel at Incheon Korea

Tags: transit, bookings, south-korea, icn

I want to stay overnight on a 2 leg international flight in Feb 2020, no need to clear customs.

Hotel says no availability, is because date is too far out?

Comment: Sorry, but how are we supposed to know better than the hotel? Phone them up or email them.

Answer (score 2):

I did this a few months ago.

**For Korean Airlines (free transit hotel):**

You need to wait until you arrive in Incheon to request the overnight hotel. Usually it is granted within a few minutes of getting to the assistant desk.

You can't book it before arriving as it's on a first-come-first-serve basis. If you arrive they will most likely put you in a hotel near the airport (they're very rarely full).

You don't contact the hotels at all. You just contact the airline desk on arrival, **you need to clear customs obviously** and then they'll give you a coupon for shuttle and hotel stay.

**For other airlines/hotels (organised and paid by traveller):**

This is entirely up to you and the hotel. It's like booking any other hotel. You can't book too early or too late as visa information may be required, etc.